# Perl Regular Expression to match special characters

Tags: regex, perl

I have the below code in which I am checking for a specific variable location in an array excluded.It works fine with all the array elements except one (abc/def/libraries/linux_3.2.60-1+deb7u3.dsc). When I provide this element as my location its printing "location not excluded" , even though its excluded.

How can I made my code to get this element as well as excluded?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @excluded = (
 "xyz/efg/headers/",
 "abc/def/libraries/jni-mr.h",
 "abc/def/libraries/linux_3.2.60-1+deb7u3.dsc", 
);

my $location = "abc/def/libraries/linux_3.2.60-1+deb7u3.dsc";
my $badpath = 0;

foreach (@excluded) {
    # -- Check if location is contained in excluded array
    if ($location =~ /^$_/) {
       $badpath = 1;
       print "location is excluded : $location \n";
     }
   }

   if (! $badpath) {
      print "location is not excluded : $location \n";  
     }
```

Desired Output:

```
location is excluded : abc/def/libraries/linux_3.2.60-1+deb7u3.dsc
```

Current Output:

```
location is not excluded : abc/def/libraries/linux_3.2.60-1+deb7u3.dsc
```

Comment: You might be better off using the `index` function if you are not going to apply any regex meta characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `quotemeta($text)` or `\Q$text\E` (inside double quotes or a regex literal) to create a pattern that matches the value of `$text`. In other words, use

```
if ($location =~ /^\Q$_\E/)
```

instead of:

```
if ($location =~ /^$_/)
```

Answer (score 0):

- It looks like you intend to define your exclusions by regex, but you have not escaped regex metachars properly in those regexes. For your failing case, the metachar causing it to fail is the plus (`+`), which is a one-or-more multiplier in most regex flavors (including Perl), but you need to match it literally.
- Also, I'd recommend moving the `^` anchor from the loop to each individual regex, which would make the code more flexible, in that you could choose not to anchor some of the exclusion regexes if you wanted.
- Also, you should use the [`qr()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qr.html) construct, which allows you to precompile regexes, saving on CPU.
- Also, this requirement is a good candidate for using [`grep()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @excluded = (
    qr(^xyz/efg/headers/),
    qr(^abc/def/libraries/jni-mr\.h),
    qr(^abc/def/libraries/linux_3\.2\.60-1\+deb7u3\.dsc),
);

my $location = 'abc/def/libraries/linux_3.2.60-1+deb7u3.dsc';

# -- Check if location is contained in excluded array
my $badpath = scalar(grep($location =~ $_, @excluded )) >= 1 ? 1 : 0;
if ($badpath) {
    print "location is excluded : $location \n";
} else {
    print "location is not excluded : $location \n";
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `scalar` there, as the expression is already in scalar context. Nor do you need to use the ternary operator.

Comment: @TLP, that's true, but two things: (1) I usually like to be explicit about scalar vs. array context. The Perl context distinction causes a lot of confusion for many people, and I'd even argue it's a detrimental feature of the language for that reason, and (2) I used the ternary operator because the OP stored 0 and 1 in `$badpath`, so I wanted to do the same (again, explicitly).

Comment: There, I modified the code to be even *more* explicit, by specifying the `>= 1` test that clarifies what happens on the LHS of the ternary operator. A lot of Perl programmers seem to be anti-explicit and pro-crytic, so they'll hate that, but screw that, it's better to be clearer than not.

Comment: I don't think it is actually any more clear when stated "explicitly", like you say. If someone does not know about scalar context, they will not understand the use of `scalar` either. It is not a transparent way to get a count. And you are also stacking expressions on one line. I would use an array, e.g. `my @count = grep ...; my $badpath = 0 # default; $badpath = 1 if @count >=1;`

Comment: Good! We agree that the use of `scalar()` to get an array's length is cryptic. But we don't really have a choice; scalar context is the way to get an array's length in Perl.

Comment: As for context, like everything else, it is easy once you know about it. And very useful for quickly writing code, e.g. `if (@count >= 1)` would not be possible to write without context dependence. I am very fond of it myself, as it allows freedom and variation when writing code. When I dabble in php, I often find myself very constricted.

Comment: Yes, unless you know how to get an array's length in Perl, it does not make sense. But once you know that an array in scalar context returns its length, it is quite easy. So one can write it in a more legible way like that. You could even do something like `my $array_length = @count` and provide self-documenting names.

Comment: Well, we do have choices, that's why TIMTOWTDI :) You can loop: `for (@array) { $length++ }`, or use the max index variable: `$length = $#array + 1`.